# How to make double question marks work for general assignment?

Tags: c#

In c# there is a  conditional operator expression.

```
var a = b ? c : d;
```

And there is a null coalescing operator:

```
var a = b ?? c;
```

But the null coalescing operator ?? only work for checking if b is null.
I believe everybody writes lots of code for reassign 'a' value to a basing on some conditions:

```
var a=whatever;
if(true)
  a = b;
```

If I can use one line code I never use two lines, in order to make them in one line I have to do like this:

```
 a = b ? a : c;
```

I am always wondering if I can find something in c# like this:

```
a = b ??? c;

if b is true 
  a = c;
else
  a is still a;
```

Comment: Are you looking for `||` and `&&`?

Comment: Looks like a Feature Request and on a wrong forum

Comment: Why would you want to use ternary operator (? : operator). What value does that add to your application, except for making your code little shorter and more cryptic?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such operator, and there is no support for adding operators to C# (only [overloading certain operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)). I'd recommend:

```
if (b)
    a = c;
```

It's clear, concise, and simple. If your guidelines don't forbid single-line `if` statements, it could even be 1 line:

```
if (b) a = c;
```

Of course, if your guidelines say to always include curly braces on their own lines, it could be 4 lines.

```
if (b)
{
    a = c;
}
```